# Opencart - Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: php, opencart

When the new orders are placed using `Paypal Express Checkout`, the details like Product Name, Qty, Price etc are posted to paypal & the Paypal recalculate the Order Totals.

Is there any way to bypass this ?

Instead of sending each product detail to Paypal, I want to send only Order Total (after calculation of all discounts, taxes etc).

```
- I want to divide the Order Total into two parts 20% + 80%. 

 - I want to get 20% through Paypal Express Checkout and 80% will be
   collected manually. 

 - I also want 80% of the total to insert into new column in
   paypal_orders table.
```

Is it possible to achieve this without bypassing ? Any help will be highly appreciated.